# Why my app is crashing when OnBackPressed is called?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to execute some javascript(webview Eval) when back button(OnBackPressed) is pressed but the app crashs. Can someone figure out what is happening?

MainActivity.cs

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        /*
     some code
    */
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }

    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        MainPage.ExecJS();
}
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
 {
    public static double ScreenWidth { get; set; }
    public static double ScreenHeight { get; set; }
    public static WebView webnav;
    StackLayout parent = null;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WebView webnav = new WebView
        {
            HeightRequest = 1000,
            WidthRequest = 1000,
            Source = "https://www.comprarmusicas.com.br/mobile/index.php"
        };
        parent = new StackLayout();
        parent.Children.Add(webnav);
        Content = parent;
    }

     public static void ExecJS()
    {
        string jsCode = "alert('ok');";
        webnav.Eval(jsCode);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning the static `WebView` variable in your .ctor but creating a new local instance variable.

Remove the `WebView` type from where you instance/assign the WebView, ie.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    webnav = new WebView // this assigns to the "public static WebView webnav;"
    {
        HeightRequest = 1000,
    ~~~
```

Comment: How can I have webview being implemented at MainPage.xaml and declared as static? I mean, something like: 
<Webview x:Name="webnav" (static) Navigated="webnav_Navigated" /> 
and have method navigated accessible on MainPage.cs. I tried and couldn't access, I think this will fix all my problems.

Comment: @ÉderRochaBezerra Assign the Webview instance variable from your 
"XAML" (which is just an instance var.) to the static one (just use a different var. name)... but remember that will cause the WebView (from the XAML) to contain a  static reference in your `MainPage` class and thus it will not get GC'd ever, so remember to `null` out that reference when you navigate away from the MainPage (like in the OnDisappearing handler), this a common problem of using static variables and the memory leaks that can occur if you are not removing those references.